# Where can I find usage statistics about Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Does it still have scalability issues ? Is a good choice for the development of a service with thousands of users ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a developer but I've just made a quick search to try answering your question.

- The following is a good review for
  GAE: [Google app engine review (Java
  edition)](http://www.royans.net/arch/google-app-engine-java-edition/)
- This is the official developer blog
  for GAE: [Google App Engine Blog
  (News, notes, tips, and tricks from
  the Google App Engine Team)](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/)
- [Google App Engine Official Online
  Docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html)

Hope that helps.